# page not found 404 - Django

Tags: python, django, документация

Изучаю джанго с помощью документации, вроде все делал правильно. Но когда захожу на http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/ выдает ошибку. Раньше таких проблем не было.
    вот polls\urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
# ex: /polls/
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
# ex: /polls/5/
url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name = 'detail'),
# ex: /polls/5/results/
url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.results, name='results'),
# ex: /polls/5/vote/
url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

polls/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Choice, Question
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import RequestContext, loader

def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    template = loader.get_template("polls/index.html")
    context = {"latest_question_list": latest_question_list}
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)

def detail(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(Request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question})

def results(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(Request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question})

def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        #redisplay the question voting form.
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
            })

    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=
        (question.id,)))
```

mysite\urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: Наверняка сообщение об ошибке сильно поможет в её решении.
Приведите также код корневого urls.py

Comment: @Pavel1114 добавил

Comment: А где сообщение об ошибке?

Answer (score 0):

Побробуйте так:

```
urlpatterns = [
# ex: /polls/5/
url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name = 'detail'),
# ex: /polls/5/results/
url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.results, name='results'),
# ex: /polls/5/vote/
url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
# ex: /polls/
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

В файле urls.py попробуйте убрать данную строчку:
`app_name = 'polls'`